# php: delete elements from string

Tags: php

I have this sitation:

```
..<img src="//http://www... OR ..<img src="/http://www... OR ..<img src="////http://www...
```

(/ - may be much)

How delete / before http?
Resultat always should be:

```
..<img src="http://www...
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: Can you show a real life example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
ltrim($url, "/");
```

This seems like a rather ad hoc solution. You might want to get to the bottom of the issue and eliminate it at source.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression along the lines of this should do the trick I think:

```
$string = preg_replace('/="\/+http:/', '="http:', $string);
```

Comment: Yes it does. Could you post proper example of what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the url is defined in a variable within your PHP, [ltrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) could be the answer

```
$url = ltrim($url,'/');
```

though you wouldn't be able to use this option if you had local url's (eg '/images/img.gif') without the 'http://'

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (`str_replace()` because it is faster than a regular expression):

```
$markup = str_replace('//http://', 'http://', $markup);
```

Why do you need this? It might be better to eliminate the source of this problem.